# How to force focus on a XAML ListView for Windows 10 apps (UWP)?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-10, uwp

I have a pivot control for which i am passing data using ItemSource property. I am also using a data template to populate the Pivot Items.

The data template has a listview inside.

```
<DataTemplate ..... >

<ListView ....></ListView>

</DataTemplate>
```

I am trying to attach keyboard events to the ListView in the page. Like scroll to top using Home key and scroll to bottom using End key.

Since the ListView is inside DataTemplate, I am unable to hookup a Keyboard event at compile time.

Approaches taken to overcome this:

1) Using KeyDown property in Xaml control

```
Result: Too much delay for the event to trigger
```

2) Using VisualTree

```
Result: Traversing creates lot of overhead.
```

3) Using ListView Loaded event

```
Result: Called only once
```

Best solution taken so far:

1) Attaching the keyboard event for GotFocus property of the ListView.

**But I wanted to force focus on the Listview as the page loads. Also, when I change pivot item, it should automatically force focus on the new ListView.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share an event handler for the ListViews in the DataTemplate. Then use the sender of the event to get the ListView instance firing the event.

From that sender you can then do what you want. For example, if I share the LoadedEvent, I'd try something like this:

```
private void ListView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lv = sender as ListView;

        if(lv != null)
            lv.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Note that this may not work as-is, so be sure to test it thoroughly that it will work for your needs. It is a fast approach.

If you're sticking to strict MVVM pattern, another option is to use a property (dependency or similar) and use a OneTime x:Bind to SelectedIndex of the ListView. I have not tested this approach, but the idea should work as you can bind to the same property for all the ListViews.

Comment: Thanks Lance :) My 3rd approach was actually using Listview and it didn't work. However I tried using util:FocusHelper.IsFocus="{x:Bind IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}" and it worked as expected.